# terminal transparency, Imagemagick, and X11 root window problem

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, x11, imagemagick

In Ubuntu Natty and in Fedora 12, I have `urxvt` (with 256 colours), and use `ImageMagick` (`display -window root [...]`) to set the root window to a picture. When I use the transparency (`-tr`) option on `urxvt`, I get the X11 login screen background (The pink/purple one in Ubunutu, the Blue one in Fedora) and not the image that is currently on the root window. See picture at the bottom -- taken from Ubuntu but similar to Fedora.

Note that the same problem exists if I run `gnome-terminal` and set its transparency.

I suspect that ImageMagick is not drawing on the right X11 layer but I (and google) cannot figure out what the right option is.

Could the problem be with either the xorg configuration or with window composition?

[image: screenshot]

I would be happy to use something else than Imagemagick as long as I can re-size the images on the fly (so it keeps its current aspect ratio and fits within the visible screen area) and that I can centre the image on the bottom right corner of the screen.

Comment: Are you sure `imagemagick` actually changes the root image, and doesn't simply overlay it? What happens if you use `imlibsetroot` or similar?

Comment: Well, it says in the documentation that it displays on the "root" window via "-window root".  Other programs (qiv for example) do the right thing but do not allow me to position the images at a random location or to scale it thus why I am not using it.

Comment: "Displays" is ambiguous. Somehow the other root image is being kept, probably because it is not being changed, but it is simply having an overlay applied.

Comment: Any idea for a fix?

Comment: Like I said, try using `imlibsetroot` and see if it helps.

Comment: So close... Yet, it does not allow to set the bottom right corner of the image on the bottom right corner of the screen.  *sigh*  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with `awesome` window manager as well as `urxvt`, when *ImageMagick* was used to set the background. It got quickly resolved with feedback from the author of `awesome` - you can see the archive of this conversation on *gmane archives* - [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.window-managers.awesome/5660/match=blurry) and further on [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.window-managers.awesome/5661/focus=5662).

The solution was to **change the background setter** and I chose to use `habak` because it was the lightest one. You can also use other, like `feh` or `Esetroot` (belongs to [Enlightenment WM](http://www.enlightenment.org/)). I think I would recommend you to try **`feh`** first, since it seems to be packaged for many distros.

*Side note: In case someone wanted to try out many different bg-setters, here's a list of those that `awsetbg` (bg-setting wrapper script from `awesome`) tries to use:*

`Esetroot habak feh hsetroot chbg fvwm-root imlibsetroot display qiv xv xsri xli xsetbg wmsetbg xsetroot`

*Note that some of those only come shipped with bigger packages.*

**Edit:** Looking at [**xsri** manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xsri), I think it might provide best flexibility for your needs.

Comment: None of those tools allow me to resize and move the final image on the root window.

Comment: I'm sure `habak` does, I use it on a dual-monitor setup.

Comment: Apparently, it can indeed.  It fails on one thing which is keeping the image to a maximum scale.  Still, better than the alternative.

Comment: Oh, great :) Your comment arrived just as I was suggesting for you to try it...

Comment: No worries.  Many thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: **Update** xsri is no longer supported and the source code is hard to find and is not guaranteed to compile -- it does not on Fedora 16.

Comment: Not really answering the question: How to get a custom scaled and positioned background image that works with transparent terminals? See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but did you try to set the image with xli?

```
xli -onroot myimage.png
```

The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/xli.1.html) says

```
NAME
       xli - load images into an X11 window or onto the root window

SYNOPSIS
       xli [global_options] {[image_options] image ...}
       xli [global_options] [image_options] stdin < image

DESCRIPTION
       xli  displays  images  in  an  X11  window  or loads them onto the root
       window.  See the IMAGE TYPES section below for supported image types.

       If the filename stdin is given, xli will read the image  from  standard
       input.
```

Comment: Do you have a url for downloading it?  With MD5 checksums if possible...  Thanks.

Comment: On Ubuntu just execute "sudo apt-get install xli" on fedora you can install (but maybe you already have it) xloadimage and you can use the same options. yum install xloadimage

Comment: You can also use xv, that normally comes as default
xv -root -quit -max /usr/local/share/wallpapers/FreeBSD/a_1600x900.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well, since xsri is no longer maintained, this is now the solution to the problem:
use `convert` to convert all images so that they are the right size and the right format, save them in another directory and use `feh` to display them.  Very inelegant indeed but works.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run this in your image directory
dir=$HOME/wallpapers
for file in *
do
    echo "Doing $file"
    convert -resize '1600x1200>' -extent 1600x1200 -background '#000000' \
        -gravity SouthEast  $file $dir/$file
done
```

Note that the *resize* option must be before the *extend* one.

Then use `feh` or whatever and centre the image on your display.  Meh.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image using Imagemagick's `convert` and pipe the result to `feh` to diplay it as background, which also works for transparent terminals:

```
convert "$file" -resize 1600x1200 png:- | feh --bg-center -
```

Of course `convert` can do almost anything to your image. Much more than **any background setter** ever will.