# Fake Transparency in URxvt Using ImageMagick in i3

Tags: i3, imagemagick, rxvt, wallpaper, feh

The most popular way to set your background in i3 seems to be using `feh`, via something like:

```
exec_always feh --bg-fill /home/user/Pictures/wallpaper.jpg
```

in your `~/.config/i3/config` file. Then, in `~/.Xresources` you can configure `URxvt` to be transparent with something like:

```
URxvt.transparent:     true
URxvt.shading:         50
URxvt.blurRadius:      0
URxvt.background:      #d3d3d3
URxvt.foreground:      #1d1f21
```

And as you can see, those two things together work perfectly with `feh` on my home computer. Ignore the horrific color scheme for now.

[image]

Now, for various reasons I don't have access to `feh` due to limited yum repos at work. I can't download and compile it myself or anything like that either. As a substitute, I've been using `ImageMagick` and its `display` functionality to set my background with:

```
exec_always display -window root /home/user/Pictures/wallpaper.jpg
```

which by itself, does set the wallpaper and works with i3.

The problem is that when I do this, it seems like `ImageMagick` has just set an overlay rather than actually setting the root image and as a result `URxvt` just reads a default grey root image. Note that this is also my home computer, where `feh` works just fine so it is not a `URxvt` problem.

[image]

1. Is there a different way to set my background using `ImageMagick` so that it actually sets the root wallpaper? This is the solution that I would prefer.
2. Are there other pieces of software, or preferably commonly pre-installed tools, that can be used to set my wallpaper? Again, keep in mind that I don't have access to things like `feh` at work, and anything else I'd have to look and see. I've seen [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/terminal-transparency-imagemagick-and-x11-root-window-problem) that mentions a few but haven't had time to check if they exist at work or not. 1. I also don't have access to things like compton, xcompmgr, etc. for true transparency.

**Update:** I have tried using `xsetroot` and converting my `.jpg` images to `.bmp` using ImageMagick's `convert`, but `xsetroot` only works with `.xbm` images which only support black and white. This won't work cause I'd like it to still be the same as the `.jpg` image shown.

Answer (score 0):

Running `ltrace` on `feh` shows it seems to create a pixmap and use XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap to attach it to the root window (193 is 0xc1 the root window id):

```
XOpenDisplay(...) = 0x22a8a50
XCreatePixmap(0x22a8a50, 193, 1920, 1080)        = 0x3000001
XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(0x22a8a50, 193, 0x3000001, ...) = 1
```

but more importantly it sets two properties on the root window:

```
XChangeProperty(0x22a8a50, 193, 312, 20)         = 1
XChangeProperty(0x22a8a50, 193, 807, 20)         = 1
```

which you can see with

```
$ xprop -root
  ESETROOT_PMAP_ID(PIXMAP): pixmap id # 0x3000001
  _XROOTPMAP_ID(PIXMAP): pixmap id # 0x3000001
```

A program like ImageMagick's `display` does not seem to update these properties when it changes the root background.

You can check after using `feh` that when you remove both of the above properties (with `xprop -root -remove ...`) programs like `urxvt` will no longer show a transparent background.

Although `xprop` has a `-set` option, I don't know how you can use it to set or change the pixmap id.

Comment: Wow, this is some good information. So the we have a Display pointer with the first Xlib call, and Pixmap with the second. Then these are both used to set the root window image. A personal program could perhaps be written to make the fourth and fifth Xlib calls, but that might be convoluted to do. What exactly is the `xprop -root` information telling me? And where is the best place to find out if this is possible with the `xprop -set ...` option?

Comment: Another weird thing that I experienced is that if I use `feh` to set the root window image and then use `display` afterwards, it still shows the one that was set by `feh` when using fake transparency in `urxvt`. Once I log out/in again however, this is all reset.

Comment: As you can see, my answer is not really an answer, but just provides some clues as to what is going on. I think that `urxvt` looks for the property `_XROOTPMAP_ID` on the root window to get the id of the background pixmap, then does its own transparency graphics operation. If you change the background with `display`, it sets a different pixmap on the root, but the property doesnt change and that old pixmap is still around, even though it is no longer attached to the root window. The [sources](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/src/app/) to X11 will not help much.